# Why was this question "deleted by Community"?

Tags: bug, deleted-questions, community-user

This question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19471650/ms-vs-2010-omit-frame-pointer-optimization-doesnt

It seems perfectly reasonable, but then, I posed it.

It didn't have a lot of upvotes, and it has had no answers, but that doesn't make it invalid.

It got a downvote yesterday for no reason that I understand.
Today, pfft.  What's the reason this happens?

Comment: Automatic delete; negative score, past a threshold of age.

Comment: This question is not a year old.

Comment: Read the *answer*, the question is more than 30 days old.

Comment: I did read it after I complainted.  You'll agree the title of the "duplicate question" response is pretty misleading.

Comment: Would you rather I linked you to the [deletion faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) instead? I gave you a more specific post, one that outlines the exact rules that apply to *this* specific question.

Comment: Frankly, yes, that would have been a better link.  I would have been tempted to read it, rather than thinking the person who closed this as duplicate didn't understand that 30 days was not the same as 1 year.  Enough, I got the message.

Comment: I don't think it's so bad at all. I'd undelete it, if no one objects strongly.

Comment: @AndrewBarber can't see any objections... go ahead! ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Undeleted!

Answer (score 2):

Community is an automated bot-thingy. It automatically deletes questions that it deems are low quality.

This question

- was 3 months old
- had a negative score
- had no answers
- had low views

Therefore, it was deemed "low quality" and deleted.

Comment: That's one way to define "low quality".  That isn't necessarily perfect.  The question describes a real problem.  It is anserable in fact.  I'm still stuck for an answer (or at least specific confirmation that the tool in question works as advertised).   As to "negative score", yes, it had a zero score, and somebody downvoted it.  There is no reasonable argument that the downvote is technically justified, and the downvoter did not give any reason.  I think this deletion is inappropriate.  Can I have the question restored?

Comment: @IraBaxter since Community is considered a moderator by the system, the only people that can undelete it are the moderators.  I can't see the question, but if you can improve it a little, I'd suggest you try that, then flag for a mod to undelete it.